# Cardinality violation error when using whereHas cause in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have Three tables named `users` and `children` and `children_access` as pivot.

I want to find all users have children with special age ranges.

There is no `age` field in `children` table and I must calculate it before select.

```
$users = User::whereHas('children',function($query){
   $query->inRange([3,4]);
});
```

in Child model I wrote this scope:

```
public function scopeInRange($query,$range_array)
{
    $sub = $query->select(DB::raw('*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age'));
    return DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
        ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
        ->whereIn('age',$range_array);
}
```

But it causes this error:

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 43 column(s) (SQL: select * from `users` where (select *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age from `children` inner join `children_access` on `children`.`id` = `children_access`.`child_id` where `children_access`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`) >= 1)
```

Comment: Does this query scope work when you call it from the *children* model, not using the *users* relationship?

Comment: @TheFallen Yes it works when I use this command:
Child::InRange([3,4])->get();

Comment: In that case I'm guessing the MySQL error comes from the `>= 1` at the end, which I don't know how to solve. If you haven't solved this yet I can suggest making 2 queries for this. First get the IDs with `Child::InRange` and then in `whereHas()` to query **where ID in**. Good luck, I hope you find a solution.

Comment: @TheFallen I checked the query in MySQL and I got same error and I think it's not depend on `>=1` But I thank you for your alternative. It works! however I'm looking for main solution.